# Convert Java int to C unsigned int

Tags: java, c

I am wondering if it would be possible to convert Java `int` to a C `unsigned int` especially if Java `int` is negative?

Edit in response to comments: the conversion isn't through JNI but rather I have a set of `int` that are written to a storage by a Java library. There exists a C version of that library but it uses `unsigned int`. I want to use the C library to read the `int` persisted by the Java library.

Comment: What do you mean with converting between java and C types? Are you talking about JNI?

Comment: @dan1st: I updated the question to clarify the conversion process.

Comment: You may be overthinking this.  If you have two libraries serving the same file format, then a good first guess would be that they are interoperable.  Do you have reason to believe that this is not the case?

Comment: @JohnBollinger: Unfortunately the libraries aren't interoperable  based on my experiments.

Comment: @swap310, then most likely either your expectations are wrong or one of the libraries is broken.  We don't have enough information to tell which.

Comment: I am also inclined to suspect that you have asked the wrong question, but at minimum you have not given us enough information to be confident of giving you the information you really want.  If the objective is, for example, to use a Java program to consume data written to the target file by a C program, then we need to know about the nature of the data, the file format, and the specific misbehavior you are seeing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on your library.

Assumung the C and Java versions of the library use the same (file) format, there are four possibilities for negative numbers/numbers out of signed int bounds:

#### Overflow

It could just overflow so that the java int would be negative while the C `unsigned int` would be a number >=2^31.

#### Exception/Error

The library could just throw an exception (this could be indicated via a special return value or flag)

#### Special value

There could be a special value for that case like `Integer.MAX_VALUE` for a number to high or `0` for a negative number.

#### Don't allow storing

The library could just not allow storing negative/too high numbers.

---

What choice is used is up to your library. You might want to consult the documentation or just try it out.

It might also be undefined/implementation defined behaviour, a combination of those cases (different between the C and Java implementations) or change between versions of your library

Answer (score 4):

If the C `unsigned int` is 32 bits then the Java `int` contains the exact same binary value, even if it is negative. Assuming you want to convert it to the equivalent positive value, you are looking for either [`Integer::toUnsignedString`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#toUnsignedString(int)) or [`Integer::toUnsignedLong`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#toUnsignedLong(int)). If you want to pass the value to a C library using JNI then it already has the desired binary value.

In response to your edit, again, if the C library is using 32-bit ints (it might not be), then it will simply get the unsigned value. So, if the Java code wrote the value `-2` (`0xfffffffe`) then the C library would read in `4294967294`, always assuming they are using the same endianness for the numbers.

(A Java ObjectOutputStream or DataOutputStream will write the bytes in big-endian order, and on many architectures C would use little-endian, but presumably the Java and C versions of the library are designed to use the same endianness.)